# how to split shape made with pen tool in flash

Tags: flash, shapes, pen

i'm having trouble trying to only split a shape made with the pen tool in Flash : if i just erase a bit of the color, the white point key stays as is, and the shape is not split. I would like to separate it because i'd like to create an Armature, between one part of the shape and the other.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different scenarios you may be describing.

1) You have a shape whose outline was drawn with the pen tool, then a fill created.
To separate parts of this shape you could use the lasso tool and then select parts to articulate using the arrow tool. However, the outline originally made by the pen tool may cause a bit of frustration. It may be easiest to simply delete the line around the fill or work with the line as in the next scenario.

2) You are working with a shape which is actually a line created by the pen tool. That is, there is no fill. The way to work with these "shapes" is to convert them. The command is Convert Lines to Fills. Once you've done that you may then work with the shape as in the first scenario.

3) You are trying to split the shape while in pen tool mode. This is the wrong way to go about this.

Comment: thanks! i would never have found the thing with the shape "filled" or not filled, it works perfectly if i erase the content and just let the line around. then the lasso, and i've got my 2 shapes separated! Thanks a lot!